# C++ reference in base class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have a logic in base class constructor. The result of the logic has to be captured in the derived class constructor in a temporary variable. Is there a way to do it?

For example

```
class Base
{
   Base() { int temp_value = some_logic;  } 
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    Derived() { // need the temp value here.. }
};
```

Thanks,
Gokul.

Comment: Have you considered making `temp_value` a protected member of the class so it is accessible to the derived class's constructor?

Comment: @Richard:: Adding a member variable is not an option, because that will increase the size of the object. Instead we can choose to recalculate the value

Answer (score 2):

I guess the easiest way I can think of would be to just separate some_logic into it's own method...

```
class Base
{
    Base() { int temp_value = initializationLogic();  }
    int initializationLogic(){ return some-logic;}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    Derived() { int temp_value_here_too = initializationLogic(); }
};
```

Comment: The result would be that the initializationLogic() is invoked twice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well i was not asking for code organization, if i am misunderstood. I was asking for a way to avoid the double calculation.

Comment: But you *rejected* the way to avoid double calculation when you said you didn't want to add a field to the class. Storing the value *is* the way to avoid double calculation.

Comment: @Jonathan: i don't want to store the value in the member, i am fine for a temporary variable to store the value

Comment: There's no way to transfer a temporary value from the constructor of the base class down to the constructor of the subclass. You must ultimately add a field to the base class in order to maintain that information long enough for the subclass to see it. Is there a reason why you don't want to change the size of the class?

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan - Actually he did find a way: [see this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850408/c-reference-in-base-class-constructor/3850475#3850475). It's quite the hack.

Comment: Okay, that's just... a foul use of references.

Comment: @Jonathan: So are you saying that the references should not be used in constructors??? Can you please explain??

Comment: The way you've used them is... creative. It's not really the reason they were created, but I'm not going to criticize.

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
class Base 
{ 
   protected int not_so_temp_value;
   Base() { not_so_temp_value = some_logic_result;  }  
}; 

class Derived : public Base 
{ 
    Derived() { // read the not_so_temp_value member here.. } 
};
```

Or:

```
class Base 
{ 
   Base(int some_logic_result) { int temp_value = some_logic;  }  
}; 

class Derived : public Base 
{ 
    static Derived* create()
    {
       int some_logic_result = some_logic;
       return new Derived(some_logic_result);
    }
    Derived(int some_logic_result) : Base(some_logic_result)
    { // use the some_logic_result here.. } 
};
```

Comment: !! Thanks for the replies. First one increases the size. Second one asks for changing the constructor. Oh yeah!!! i can make the extra one as a default parameter. Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

This is the one i am planning to use

```
class Base 
{ 
   Base(int& some_logic_result) { some_logic_result = some_logic;  }  
}; 

class Derived : public Base 
{ 
    Derived(int some_logic_result = 0) : Base(some_logic_result)
    { // use the some_logic_result here.. } 
};
```

Thanks,
Gokul.